# Return 1 value based on conditions

Tags: excel

We have the data below:

```
Database   Scenario 2.    Other Column

1.         Q1
1.         C1
1.         D1
2.         Q1          
2.         D1
```

I'd like a 1 value returned in the other column, if both Q1 and C1 appear for the same Database, so column 1, 2 would return a 1 value however row 3 to 5 would return 0 because row 3 isn't Q1 or C1, and row 4 and 5 are in the same DB but a q1 and c1 don't exist at least once in DB 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(AND($B2="Q1",COUNTIFS($B:$B,"C1",$A:$A,$A2)>=1),AND($B2="C1",COUNTIFS($B:$B,"Q1",$A:$A,$A2)>=1)),1,0)
```

Comment: Great, what do I do if I want to add another condition to it for example the DB must also include D1, so in the example above, the first three rows would return 1 but would be 0 if D1 wasn't there

Comment: A little longer: `=IF(AND(OR($B2={"Q1","C1","D1"}),COUNTIFS($B:$B,"Q1",$A:$A,$A2)>=1,COUNTIFS($B:$B,"C1",$A:$A,$A2)>=1,COUNTIFS($B:$B,"D1",$A:$A,$A2)>=1),1,0)`